# How to share Ref using custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to keep a global reference on my custom component and use it other places but somehow my hook `useHookWithRefValue` doesn't return me update ref value, though I have found the workaround with `useHookWithRef` but I am trying to avoid ref.current every time. What could be reason behind this behaviour?

What is the explanation behind this?

```js
import React from "react";

export const textFieldRef = React.createRef(null);

export function useHookWithRef() {
  return textFieldRef; // Works!!
}

export function useHookWithRefValue() {
  return textFieldRef.current; // Always returns null
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Comment: @itaydafna How can i share then with other components https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-montalcini-mnkpw

Comment: I've added an answer on how this can be achieved using  React context and a callback-ref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the second hook always returns `null` is that it basically returns the value of the `textFieldRef.current` at the time of its creation, which is `null`. When the text-field element renders, React tells the `ref.current` to point to the input element, but this doesn't trigger a re-render and will not make your hook output an updated value.

The first hook on the other hand, returns a reference to the ref object, so if you check the `current` after React set the ref's current to point to the text-field element, you will get the actual element.

One thing you can do is use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) in order to set your text-field-element on some global state as soon as it renders:

```
<input ref={inputElement => setTextFieldElement(inputElement)} />
```

Then you can pass this state to any other component which needs to use the text-field element ref using [React context](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-darkness-xuru1?file=/src/App.js).

This will also allow you to pass only the text-field-element in the context without using `.current` every time you want to use it.

I've implemented this solution based on the sandbox you provided:
https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68234884-xuru1?file=/src/App.js

However, for your use-case, this might be an overkill and you could just stick with calling `.current` whenever you use this ref.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I guess you are right at this moment i can't make big change in codebase as this is being used at many places. I will keep using `.current` for now